# Разделение дат переносом

Tags: оформление-текста

Есть ли строгое правило не разбивать числовые словосочетания (если их можно так назвать) переносом на следующую строку?
Например:
5 мая,
5
мая;
1957 года,
1957
года;
XX века,
XX
века;
10 часов,
10
часов;
100 рублей,
100
рублей
и т. п.
Или это решается редактором конкретно по ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё перечисленное разрешено. Правила можно посмотреть [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/141-perenos).

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку. Но там, по-моему, ровно наоборот:  § 120. НЕЛЬЗЯ переносить сокращенные обозначения мер, отрывая их от цифр, указывающих число измеряемых единиц, например:
1917/г.
72/м2
53/км
10/кг

Comment: @Рад Вы невнимательны. Да, сокращённые нельзя отрывать, но в Ваших примерах таких нет. Правила переноса действуют так, что "разрешено всё, что не запрещено".

Comment: Спасибо, действительно так. Но я где-то читал (слышал), что подобные "наращения" ЛУЧШЕ не переносить, поэтому  у меня и возник этот вопрос: насколько ЛУЧШЕ не переносить, или это кто-то просто ПРИДУМАЛ, и про это можно забыть (а то я обычно напрягаю с этим верстальщика)?

Comment: @Рад, я не помню, чтобы встречал где-то такие рекомендации, но из эстетических соображений сам тоже старался бы избегать (когда-то давно работал верстальщиком, поэтому понимаю, о чём говорю). Тем более, что в современных системах компьютерной вёрстки этот процесс можно почти полностью автоматизировать.

Comment: Значит буду писать верстальщику исправлять ПО ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ. Спасибо большое!